# Upgrade website from joomla 1.5.20 to 1.5.26

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, joomla1.5

I want to upgrade my site from 1.5.20 to 1.5.26. Please guide me on how to upgrade it. My Website is 
http://xaydunglala.com
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To update minor revisions like this you can normally just unzip the files on your computer and upload them over the top via FTP